# If javascript snippet is unused it blocks other javascript from working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code to have a fixed header on scroll. On the pages it is used, other javascript works without a problem, but on the pages I don't have the class "top" and don't use the fixed header it breaks other javascript. How can I prevent this? Should I first check if the class exist on the page?

```
var fixmeTop = $('ul.top').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Learn to use your console.  You are getting an error which is preventing other javascript from running, because if `ul.top` doesn't exist, then your first line `$('ul.top').offset().top;` is throwing an error, which is preventing the rest of the scripts on the page from running.

Comment: You just described exactly what he asked. He knows that is the issue, it appears to me, he wants to know how is this usually handled.

Comment: `$("ul.top").addClass("top")` .... seriously?

Comment: Out of curiosity, and to his question: is there a way to keep trying to execute the rest of the scripts even if something like this fails? Probably try catch is a good idea but i mean, if anything like this happens in any script, is the rest of the scripts always doomed?

Comment: Once `$( "ul.top" ).removeClass( "top" )` has executed, `$( "ul.top" )` will select nada, and `position:'fixed'` etc will never be reapplied. If that's what you want, then carry on.

Comment: @Ernesto, no the rest of the scripts are not always doomed, only any unexecuted remainder of the event thread in which an uncaught error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error which is preventing other javascript from running, because if ul.top doesn't exist, then your first line $('ul.top').offset().top; is throwing an error, which is preventing the rest of the scripts on the page from running.

Wrap your code inside of an `if` block that checks if the element exists before attempting to execute:

```
if ($('ul.top').length) {
    var fixmeTop = $('ul.top').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
            $( "ul.top" ).addClass( "top" );
            $('ul.top').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0',           
                left: 'auto'
            });
        } else {
            $( "ul.top" ).removeClass( "top" );
            $('ul.top').css({
                position: 'relative',   
                top: '0'             
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You would see this if you would use your browser console tools: [How to Use Browser Console](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+browser+console)

Comment: Correct answer, although `var ul_top = $('ul.top')` then replacing all other instances of `$('ul.top')` with the variable `ul_top` (e.g. `if( ul_top.length)`, etc.) would be more efficient

Comment: @Adam - Totally agree.  The scope of the question is such that I'm not inclined to speak to all best practices such as your suggestion, though!

Comment: if ($'ul.top').length) { has an syntax error: think it is missing a ( before 'ul

Comment: @coder - Maintainability, mostly.  If you take Adam's suggestion, it makes the code more maintainable (if you ever change the selector class, you only have to change it one place, instead of several). It may result in *slightly* better performance, but that's not the real concern here.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap a check for the class around your code. e.g.

```
 if ($('.top').length) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer lies in your initial two lines which says

```
var fixmeTop = $('ul.top').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {

--code 
}
```

On your first line you have $('ul.top') which will give you undefined and then you are using .offset - which I believe should give you undefined is not a function.

Ideally you should be checking if that class exists then only do something. If not, dont execute this entire block because your windows scroll method uses fixmetop which wont exist when this class itself wont exist

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning